# How to control UIScrollView automatically scrolling on FirstResponder / Keyboard changes?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

**TL;DR**

Is it a new feature in Xcode 14 and iOS 16 that a `UIScrollView` is now scrolled automatically when a view inside the ScrollView becomes firstReponder and the keyboard appears? While working on other iOS projects in earlier versions of Xcode and iOS I never came across this behaviour. Can this be controlled or deactivated?

**Details:**

While working with Xcode 14.0.1 on a new iOS project I noticed that an `UIScrollView` is now automatically scrolled when the content view becomes first responder.

Have a look at this example. I have created a new project, added a ScrollView to the ViewController and placed 12 subviews inside to fill it with some content. Subview no. 12 additionally holds a `UITextField`. The firstResponder status of this text field can be toggled using the top button.

When tapping on the button the TextField becomes firstResponder and the ScrollView is automatically scrolled up. However, not enough to make bring the TextField above the keyboard and make visible. Just enough to bring it above the bottom screen edge.

This does not make a lot of sense to me.

**Is it possible to control this automatic scrolling or to deactivate it?**

[image]

EDIT:

I have created `CustomScrollView` as `UIScrollView` subclass and did override `scrollRectToVisible`. When calling `super.scrollRectToVisible` everything works as before, but I could set a break point to see from where `scrollRectToVisible` is called.

The callstack shows the method `scrollTextFieldToVisibleIfNecessary` inside `UITextField` which uses `delegateShouldScrollToVisibleWhenBecomingFirstResponder`

However, UITextFileDelegate does not have such a method / value and `scrollTextFieldToVisibleIfNecessary` is also documented nowhere.

**So, the question remains: How to disable this behaviour?**